# How to make Entity Framework CTP5 work with SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, sqlite, ef-code-first

I am having a very hard time in using the SQLite db with EF CTP5. I was just trying to execute this [MSDN example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) with SQLite. But at the line

```
var food = db.Categories.Find("FOOD");
```

I am getting a runtime exception:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): SQLite errorno such table: Categories

Note: The app.config file has to be modified and is as follows:

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductContext" connectionString="Data Source=D:\CodeFirst.db;Version=3;New=True;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe the EF forum in System.Data.SQLite's site is a better place to ask? http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that current SQLite.net does not support Entity Framework CTP5 code first. Will have to wait for that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

System.Data.SQLite does not provide CreateDatabase() and DeleteDataase() dynamic database creation at the moment. At least, [this forum post](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2707/10213.aspx#10213) is unanswered for approximately a month.
We already offer both dynamic database creation and CTP 5 support, and plan to blog about CTP 5 support in [dotConnect for SQLite](http://devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/) soon.
**UPDATE**. The [CTP 5 article](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html) is available. It contains some notes concerning database creation peculiarities, and a sample illustrating CTP 5 usage.

Comment: Devart - eagerly awaiting the blog post.  I can find NO information about dotconnect for sqlite with code first ctp5.  None!  I have even posted in the Devart forum and sent an email from the Devart website.

Comment: @user327325, we have released the article. See the update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this:

http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDataContext>(null);
```

works for me. I use `EF5` code first with `Sqlite`